# Sphinx error on Readthedocs: "TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

The build of a documentation on Readthedocs failed with an Sphinx error quite difficult to understand:

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/fluidimage/envs/latest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/ext/viewcode.py", line 61, in has_tag
  if entry is None or entry[0] != code:
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

for the full log, see https://readthedocs.org/projects/fluidimage/builds/3758665/

I found that the same kind of issue has been experienced by other projects
([link to the google search](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22sphinx%22+%22TypeError:+%27bool%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27__getitem__%27%22)), but it does not help me to understand what happens.

What does this error mean? How can it be solved?

Comment: Check 3.4 here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html . I think the compiler interprets entry as a bool an therefore you cannot access it in this way

Comment: Evidently it's expecting `entry` to either be `None` or a sequence (list, tuple, string, etc.), but that's not what it's getting. Without a [mcve], we can't tell you why.

Comment: Quite difficult to obtain a MCVE with that kind of problem. I am happy it is solved and I hope that this question and the answer can help those getting the same problem, even though nothing is explained.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So a practical answer to my question can be

- wait
- commit a modification with nearly nothing
- build again...

and the Sphinx-Readthedocs bug goes away. At least it is what happens to me.

Comment: u might as well delete this answer as it is useless

Comment: u might as well delete this comment as it is useless :-)

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be related to [this sphinx issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5459). While sphinx has updated itself to allow `autodoc_default_options` to be defined as `True`, it might be that readthedocs is using an older version of sphinx or is unable to accept these values for some reason. Changing the values in the `autodoc_default_options` dict to `None` allows the build to continue.

Example :

```
autodoc_default_options = {
    'members': None, 'undoc-members': None,
    'private-members': None, 'show-inheritance': None
}
```